# Traffic going through default interface when there is a static route available

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing

I have a host only VirtualBox network that I'm trying to interact with. The routes on my host seem to be configured properly but I can't interact with `vboxnet`.

When I `traceroute`, it seems that traffic is going out through my default gateway instead of through the static route.

```
# route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         Windows-Phone.m 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.57.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet1
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
# traceroute 192.16.57.200
traceroute to 192.16.57.200 (192.16.57.200), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  Windows-Phone.mshome.net (192.168.137.1)  4.471 ms * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

I don't understand why this would happen, and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If I see correctly, you have just misstyped the address. You were trying to reach 192.**16**.57.200 (16 as a second octet) instead of 192.**168**.57.200. So the default gateway has been selected, because there was no direct way.